# How to use obscure types like ExerciseGym?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I've found this type on Schema.org: [`ExerciseGym`](https://schema.org/ExerciseGym)

It doesn't have any examples with it and I'm confused as to how to use it because it seems to inherit properties from other schemas.  This one is more specific to the business so ideally I'd like to use it.

It says "properties from `LocalBusiness`". I have used `LocalBusiness` before, and it contains good examples.  Should I combine `LocalBusiness` and `ExerciseGym` and `Person` as I would like to list the personal trainers of the gym as `employee` but it says `employee` is `Person`?

So is something like this the right way to do this:

```html
<div class="contact" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ExerciseGym https://schema.org/LocalBusiness https://schema.org/Person" itemprop="employee">
  <div class"name" itemprop="name">John Doe Does</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type "includes" all its parent types. An [`ExerciseGym`](https://schema.org/ExerciseGym) is *also* a `SportsActivityLocation`, a `LocalBusiness`, an `Organization`, a `Place`, and a `Thing`.

So you don’t have to specify `ExerciseGym` and `LocalBusiness`, specifying `ExerciseGym` is sufficient.

If you specify `Person` in addition to `ExerciseGym`, you are conveying: *There is something that is a person and a gym.* This is of course not want you want to say. To add an employee, you need two separate items: the gym and the person. In Microdata, an item is created with the `itemscope` attribute.

Example with an `ExerciseGym` that has two employees:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ExerciseGym">

  <div itemprop="employee" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <span itemprop="name">John</span>
  </div>

  <div itemprop="employee" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <span itemprop="name">Alice</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: So for example if there was another span with "personal trainer" it may be that it would have `itemprop="jobTitle hasOccupation"` and that would be ok?

Comment: @Eoin: You can add those properties inside the `Person` item, yes. But you probably don’t want to specify both properties in the same element, because they would share the value, but `jobTitle` expects a text value, while `hasOccupation` expects another item as value: `Occupation`.